# Firebase deploy Error: Must supply a public directory using "public" in each "hosting" config

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I was following tutorial on this page https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/google-sheet-sync. When I finaly reached step 11 where I need to deploy this project I got this error: 
"**Must supply a public directory using "public" in each "hosting" config**". After some googling I changed my firebase.jsom from this:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/oauthcallback",
        "function": "oauthcallback"
      },
      {
        "source": "/authgoogleapi",
        "function": "authgoogleapi"
      },
      {
        "source": "/testsheetwrite",
        "function": "testsheetwrite"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "functions",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/oauthcallback",
        "function": "oauthcallback"
      },
      {
        "source": "/authgoogleapi",
        "function": "authgoogleapi"
      },
      {
        "source": "/testsheetwrite",
        "function": "testsheetwrite"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It helped and project was successfully deployed, but at step 12 I got error "**SITE NOT FOUND**". After some more googling I found this https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/446, but I don't understand last comment. What does full firebase deploy that includes hosting means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is talking about the official docummentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart) that indicates the `Hosting` part of your Firebase application. This can be achieved by using the command `firebase init`. Once this is run, it will creates the `firebase.json` file that you needs to configure your paths, hosting, etc.

In addition, as the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#the_firebasejson_file) indicates:

> The firebase.json file is required to deploy assets with the Firebase CLI because it specifies which files and settings from your project directory are deployed to your Firebase project.

So, this means that you need to run the "full deploy", so you will have your jsojn file correctly created and add the hosting configuration from your project as indicated in [this comment](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/446#issue-350666702) to the constant `FUNCTIONS_REDIRECT`.

Once you have done that, you should not have issues with the deployment anymore.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thank you for your awnswer. But this project already has `firebase.json` file and github page says nothing about `firebase init` command. I run it anyway and it says that I already have some files (`package.json, index.js`) should I overwrite these files?

Comment: Hi @AlexsandrKrivobokov I would save your files first, before overwriting, so you don't lost what you have already done. But I think it might be worth it a try running  the `firebase init` command and then using the configuration as indicated by the user [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/446#issue-350666702).

Comment: So I ran `firebase init`, overwritten everything. Then I replaced the files in the functions folder (index.js, package.json, .eslintrc.json) with the originals. Then I launched `firebase deploy`. After successful completion, I reopened the page from step 12. It says that the installation of Firebase Hosting is complete. I also see all 4 functions in my Firebase console, but they do not work right now. I did not change the `FUNCTIONS_REDIRECT` constant. Do you think I should change this constant or I made a mistake in some other step? Thank you by the way for helping me

Comment: I think it's a good idea, @AlexsandrKrivobokov This way, you can test it out and verify if indeed the problem was the same or if it's something diferent.

Comment: So I did as it is written in this post. I updated my authorized redirect URI in the Google APIs to https://us-central1-{MY-PROJECT-ID}.cloudfunctions.net/. Changed const FUNCTIONS_REDIRECT. Now, when I go to the authgoogleapi function URL, I get this error: The redirect URI in the request, https://us-central1-{MY-PROJECT-ID}.cloudfunctions.net/oauthcallback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.

Comment: Ok, I found a problem: I had to insert the full URL in authorized redirect URI field  like this `https://us-central1-krpk-b23b5.cloudfunctions.net/oauthcallback` insteadof `https://us-central1-krpk-b23b5.cloudfunctions.net/`

Comment: That's great @AlexsandrKrivobokov ! I'm glad to hear that it worked. If you think my answer helped you, please, consider upvoting/accepting it! :)